# How to fetch IP Address of a user who gives print job to a printer using libcups API

Tags: 14.04, printing, smb, cups-lpd

I am using CUPS protocol and created Ubuntu machine as a print server and added printers on to my ubuntu server machine and shared those printers in the company.
Now these printers are visible to every employee of our company and when they print the page to these shared printers,i can fetch the print job data(such as title of the page,size of the page,username who has given print,creation time of the print job,printer Name) using cupsgetjobs() API as mentioned in libcups library,but i am unable to fetch the IP address from whom print job was given.

Kindly help me in getting the IP address of the user who has given the print job to the cups server.